# .htaccess redirect FROM subfolder to domain name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, root, subdirectory

I had website content in a subfolder (http://mydomain.com/subfolder/index.php), now I copied everything over to the root folder (http://mydomain.com/index.php).

I would like to redirect all the visitors that have bookmarked the old page to the new content (at least to the new index.php) using .htaccess.

Is this correct:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /subfolder/^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com [R=301,L]
```

?

And where would I place the .htaccess file, in the subfolder or the root folder?

Answer (score 31):

Placing the following `.htaccess` in `/` (where your index.php is located) should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or you could place the following `.htaccess` in `/subfolder`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that the `()` around `.*` and the `$1` redirects `/subfolder/someFile.php` to `/someFile.php`. If you skip it, everything in `/subfolder` redirects to `/`.

Comment: I added the file to the root folder, but the redirection doesn't work.

Comment: I found this solution: https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/quick-htaccess-redirect-from-subfolder.1155735/ and it seems to work.

Comment: It's essencially the same solution as above. I'll include it as an option

Comment: And I realized that I had a opening slash on the rule that is not supposed to be there. Both are updated to match both cases. (And includes some 'magic' to keep the files to reference appropriatly.

Comment: What if I want http://example.com/subfolder (without a trailing slash) to also redirect?

Comment: I modified to include the "no trailing /" case: `RewriteRule ^subfolder(/.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 2):

*Thanks to [@mariusnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1419036/mariusnn) in the comments, I was able to solve this issue.*

---

❌ Not Working: .htaccess redirect FROM subfolder to domain name

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

✅ [Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710314/htaccess-redirect-from-subfolder-to-domain-name/14710380): .htaccess redirect entire subdomain "/subdomain/" and files "/subdomain/file_01.php" within are redirected to domain name "example.com"

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^subfolder/.*$ / [R=301,L]
```

*Note that the `()` around `.*` and the `$1` redirects `/subfolder/someFile.php` to `/someFile.php`. If you skip it, everything in `/subfolder` redirects to `/`.

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subfolder$ http://yourdomain.tld/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^subfolder/index.php$ /index.php[NC,L,R]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried all answers here. This is what worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,NC,L]
```

Change `R=302` to `R=301` after you've validated the changes.