# Redirect entire sub-directory to root directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

So I am trying to clean up my search engine redirect errors. I had some old development sites that got indexed that I want to redirect to the main site.

Basically I want everything in the /dev/ folder to go to https://myfakewebsite.com/

I added this to .htaccess file in the /dev/ directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I tried this but it doesn't quite work, it does take out the /dev/ but it keeps the rest of the link there.

For example: https://myfakewebsite.com/dev/index.php?route=product/category&path=122

redirects to: https://myfakewebsite.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=122

I want it to redirect to: https://myfakewebsite.com/ (removing the /index.php?route=product/category&path=122 part).

Is there a way to do this with .htaccess?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect FROM subfolder to domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710314/htaccess-redirect-from-subfolder-to-domain-name)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that particular Q because the `/dev` folder in this instance did not get "moved up" to replace the root as int he linked question. I'm sure there's another duplicate around here for something like this though.

Comment: One Q. Are you sure you want to remove all access to `/dev/` via the 301? Or, are you trying to prevent unauthorized access to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule in your `/dev/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule  (.*) / [L,R=301]
```

The rule above redirects all requests from `/dev` to the root of site ie . `/dev/*` => `/` including query strings from `/dev?querystring` to `/?querystring` . By default mod-rewrite appends old query string to the  destination path so if you do not want it then you can use `QSD` flag in your rule or you can another rule to handle and remove QUERY_STRING .

You can use the following rules to redirect  urls with and without  query string to `/` . The `?` at the end of the rule's destination  discards the old query string.

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect /dev?querystring to /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule  (.*) /? [L,R=301]
# redirect /dev/uri to /
RewriteRule  (.*) / [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing these redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to achieve this kind of "trivial" redirect with the `RedirectMatch` directive from `mod_alias`, instead of doing this with `mod_rewrite`.

```
RedirectMatch 301 "/dev/(.*)" "/$1"
```

*See documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html.*

Answer (score 0):

You left the match results as part of the redirect on this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Specifically `$1` as part of `/$1` (the redirecting portion of the rule). Since this file is within the `/dev` directory it automatically removes `/dev/` then applies the match to the redirect. Since you are using the capture (`$1`) as part of the rule, it'll take everything it matched after `/dev/` (in your rule you should read it as `^/dev/(.*)$`) and apply it to `/$1`, where `$1` is whatever it "found" during `^(.*)$` in the previous step.

Try removing the pattern match, e.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
```

Additionally, since you aren't using the results of the match you can remove the parenthesis (e.g. `^.*$`). You can also put this `.htaccess` file in the root and simply redirect `^/dev(/?.*)$` to `/` depending on how you want to manage your subdirectories.