# Prestashop : Add a subfolder in url after a migration

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, prestashop-1.6

I have an ecommerce website built with Prestashop 1.6 with thousands of urls indexed on Google. Previously, Prestashop was installed on a subfolder. So a category url is like : domain.com/shop/en/1-category-name (there are 3 different languages).
From now on, I need to install it on the main folder and the urls will be like : domain.com/en/1-category-name.

For SEO purposes, I need to keep the same structure in order to avoid too much 301 redirections.

I would have the option to add this "shop" folder in the SEO & URLs menu of Prestashop to have something like **shop/category/{id}-{rewrite}** but the result of the url will be **domain.com/en/shop/1-category** and not **domain.com/shop/en/1-category-name** as before.

Does anyone please know if there is a way to handle this kind of issue ? Maybe directly in the htaccess ? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: this is a pretty straightfoward subfolder to root redirect.... see this question => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710314/htaccess-redirect-from-subfolder-to-domain-name

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I did indicate that "I need to keep the same structure". Making a 301 isn't an option in my case.